# Download all m3u8 files AWS CLI Through Unknown options: --include,*.m3u8

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, aws-cli

Can the AWS CLI tool be used to only list/retrieve certain file types in S3? I was trying:

```
aws s3 ls --summarize --human-readable --recursive s3://cloudfront.abc.com/CDNSource/hls/ --include "*.m3u8"
```

> but receiving "Unknown options: --include,*.m3u8"

I have tried to **grep** but it will just filter the return, so the sum will still be incorrect. I need to download all m3u8 files and then reupload them with a change.

what's the best way to do that? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try moving the `--include "*.m3u8"` before the `s3://...` URI

Comment: Also everything is included by default so exclude them all first and then just include what you want: `aws s3 ls --summarize --human-readable --recursive --exclude "*" --include "*.m3u8" s3://cloudfront.abc.com/CDNSource/hls/`

Comment: `--include` is not a command listed on the [documentation for s3 ls](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3/ls.html).  The command does not support the feature you're looking for, you'll need to use some external command to do the summary after filtering.

Comment: @Ermiya Eskandary
, I got this new error " Unknown options: --exclude,--include,*.m3u8,s3://cloudfront.abc.com/CDNSource/hls/"

Comment: @AnonCoward Ah yes, I'm making stuff up! You're right

Comment: I also tried this : sudo find /mnt/sam/ -name "*.m3u8" -exec sed -i 's/cloud(flare2?|front)[.]abc[.]com/abccdn2.ccindex.cn/g' {} \; but not working it doesnt replace.

Comment: If you're downloading, then modifying, then uploading, have a look at `aws s3 sync` which has `--include` and `--exclude` options.